# Broken build if a too big picture is included in a framed environment, how to insert "horizontal slices" rather?

Tags: graphics, framed, includegraphics, sphinx

This produces about 5000 pages before crashing:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{framed}
  \noindent\includegraphics[height=35cm]{example-image-a}\par
  % \kern-33cm\penalty0
  % \kern10cm\penalty0
  % \kern10cm\penalty0
  % \kern10cm\penalty0
  % \kern3cm
\end{framed}
\end{document}
```

or to get more real-life case

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{15cm}
\begin{framed}
  \noindent\includegraphics[height=20cm]{example-image-a}\par
\end{framed}
\end{document}
```

Adding breakpoints by de-commenting out the "kern" lines "solves" this, of course the included graphic is too big.

> in second example, the compilation succeeds if height is say at most 18cm and framed picture ends up then on page 2, but it fails for 18.55cm (for info `\textheight` is `19.33cm` here.)

I thought, maybe I can use multiple `\includegraphics` with `trim` option to insert only say a `\baselineskip` high horizontal slice of the image. Hoping that the backend pdftex or xetex will include the image file only once for all such successive horizontal slices. (real use case is a png image). Hoping too that there will be no artefact (from anti-aliasing or whats not) in PDF for the list of successive "horizontal slices" allowing suitable pagebreak.

Problem is the "trimming" should be done relative to rescaled picture for a total height of 35cm (forget in this example that it is too wide, too). I looked at the graphicx documentation but failed to see how to do that easily.

What about this problem if using other framing tools `tcolorbox`, `mdframed`?

---

From further testing, my original issue is clearly solved by ensuring that the included graphics has a height reasonably smaller than `\textheight` as the contents will be shifted to next page if not enough room, and the infinite loop arises if `framed` does not find enough room on new page.

But my question about "horizontal slices" still stands.

---

About avoiding the problem with `framed` and keeping into account the `\includegraphics` are not manually written but originates elsewhere, I will fix it this way:

```
\makeatletter
\newbox\my@image@box
\newdimen\my@image@maxheight
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \my@image@maxheight\textheight
  \advance\my@image@maxheight -2.5\baselineskip % -20pt not enough in my testing
}
\newcommand*{\myincludegraphics}[2][]{%
    \gdef\my@includegraphics@options{#1}%
    \setbox\my@image@box\hbox{\includegraphics[#1,draft]{#2}}%
    \in@false
    \ifdim \wd\my@image@box>\linewidth
      \g@addto@macro\my@includegraphics@options{,width=\linewidth}%
      \in@true
    \fi
    % no rotation, no need to worry about depth
    \ifdim \ht\my@image@box>\my@image@maxheight
      \g@addto@macro\my@includegraphics@options{,height=\my@image@maxheight}%
      \in@true
    \fi
    \ifin@
      \g@addto@macro\my@includegraphics@options{,keepaspectratio}%
    \fi
    \setbox\my@image@box\box\voidb@x % clear memory
    \expandafter\includegraphics\expandafter[\my@includegraphics@options]{#2}%
}
\makeatother
```

This ensures the width does not exceed `\linewidth` and the height something a bit smaller than `\textheight` to allow some room for `framed`.

---

@DavidCarlisle code, with a loop added:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{graphicx,adjustbox}

\usepackage{xinttools}
\begin{document}

\vspace*{15cm}

\raggedbottom
\begin{framed}\parskip0pt \lineskip0pt

%\noindent\clipbox{0 30cm 0  0cm}{\includegraphics[height=35cm,width=\linewidth]{temp}}
\xintFor*#1in{\xintdimensions[0pt+\baselineskip]}:
{%
  \noindent\clipbox{0 {\dimexpr35cm-\baselineskip-#1} 0 #1}%
    {\includegraphics[height=35cm,width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}\par
  \ifdim\dimexpr#1+\baselineskip>35cm 
   \expandafter\xintBreakFor
  \fi
}
\end{framed}
\end{document}
```

The screenshot is from Adobe Reader. However one sees some separation between the slices.

[image]

In Skim.app also I see artefacts: (not very visible here)

[image]

Comment: How could be possible to insert a `height=35cm` image in a standard sized document?

Comment: @Sigur, how it could be possible is precisely my question! (but I agree my inital posting had bad wording, I hope it got clearer after).

Comment: you can't just do what framed originally do? save the whole frame in `\vbox` and then `\vsplit`?

Comment: @touhami, no (untested) `\vsplit` can't split something unsplittable.

Comment: oh yes, my bad. No such problem with `tcolorbox`.

Comment: @touhami really? that's interesting.

Comment: @touhami in my comment about `\vsplit` I meant that yes that will reduce dimension but it will not actually "split" the image. So you are right one gets rid of some error, but by lying to TeX about actual size of image, which one can do with no `\vsplit` at all. (after the `\vsplit` the original box is empty, the entire graphics is in the new box)

Comment: @jfbu I was wrong

Comment: @jfbu why do you want a little height for the horizontal slice ? isn't better to split in three : left space in page + n times textheight + left height from image? I think this is what framed does.

Comment: @jfbu please why here is for  question not objection :-)

Comment: @touhami I think your suggestion is about "top" (first page), "n textheight", (n pages) and "bottom" (on last page). This is, imho, very difficult. First, I currently don't know what is the exact maximal height which will go through, it involves `\fboxsep`, `\fboxrule`, `\textheight`, and other parameters (it depends if 10pt or 12pt for example). Second, we would need to record `\pagetotal` _before_ being inside `framed`. Third, this `\pagetotal` is not very reliable as TeX will make various tries with glue and an error of `1sp` is enough to make difference between ...

Comment: @touhami ... aborted and succesfull PDF build in this context. Hence, the approach is to make slices and let `TeX+framed` make the appropriate choice of pagebreaks.

Comment: @touhami: framed constructs a big `\vbox` and then applies `\vsplit` by checking page parameters `\pagegoal`, `\pagetotal`, this is quite complex, and of course the `\vsplit` can only succeed if the contents offers breakpoints; by definition this is not the case with an image. We can use as proposed by David `\clipbox`, but if we do not want to rewrite entirely a framed.sty dedicated to this problem, we can only offer standard framed.sty suitable breakpoints.

Comment: @touhami However you are right we could try to localize the "slices" near where we can estimate a priori that the pagebreak will occur (by checking `\pagetotal` before `framed` environment). Yes, this is feasible. Some effort, though... Remember that this has to be fully automatized in my context.

Comment: @jfbu yes that could be (it's indeed) complexe, thanks :-)

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{graphicx,adjustbox}


\begin{document}

\vspace*{15cm}

\raggedbottom
\begin{framed}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}

\noindent\clipbox{0 30cm 0  0cm}{\includegraphics[height=35cm,width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}

\noindent\clipbox{0 25cm 0  5cm}{\includegraphics[height=35cm,width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}

\noindent\clipbox{0 20cm 0 10cm}{\includegraphics[height=35cm,width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}

\noindent\clipbox{0 15cm 0 15cm}{\includegraphics[height=35cm,width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}

\noindent\clipbox{0 10cm 0 20cm}{\includegraphics[height=35cm,width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}

\noindent\clipbox{0  5cm 0 25cm}{\includegraphics[height=35cm,width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}

\noindent\clipbox{0  0cm 0 30cm}{\includegraphics[height=35cm,width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}

\end{framed}


\end{document}
```

Comment: too bad `\clipbox` switches to LR mode is there some `\vbox` version so that I could prevent insertion of glue and only add breakpoints?

Comment: testing with a 150K png (a screenshot) I have nice surprise the PDF weighs only about 100K !

Comment: really cool that PDF size does not increase with number of `\includegraphics`,  I tried pdftex and xetex

Comment: @jfbu `\hbox{\clipbox{....` or just set `\parskip` to 0pt

Comment: nice, I think you could add that to your answer. Of course I will delay the green tick fo after a reasonable period of pondering the pros and cons... `:)`

Comment: I also need `\lineskip0pt ` or similar...

Comment: @jfbu you also have write access to this answer:-)

Comment: ok, do you mind if I add a loop doing slices of height `\baselineskip`? or should I add it to my OP?

Comment: @jfbu sure any real code based on this would have a loop of some sort.